# Как перенести изменения с одной ветки в другую

Tags: git, gitlab

Есть изменения файлов в одной ветке `branch1`. Файлов около 50 штук, я их не добавлял для отслеживания. При запуске команды `git status` они подсвечиваются красным. Как мне взять и вынести все эти изменения в ветку `branch2`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Делаешь ветку, встаешь на нее, комитишь и готово:

```
git checkout -b branch2
git add .
git commit -m "trash"
git checkout branch1
```

Comment: Или, если я не правильно понял первый раз и ветка branch2 у же есть, то ты можешь просто сделать на нее checkout и неотслеживаемые файлы останутся, потом ты можешь их комитить

Comment: Не отслеживаемые и не добавленные в комит - разные вещи
если файлы трекаются гитом, но ты их еще не закомитил, можешь сделать Stash, перейти на другую ветку, сделать pop stash и комитить